# Is there any way to force Windows.Web.Http.Httpclient to send request with HTTP1.1

Tags: uwp, httpclient

I'm developing an UWP APP, recently I got an issue on a few Windows 10 devices while trying to send a get request to the server with Windows.Web.Http.Httpclient, and the request will be rejected by the server.

After checking, I found the request send by the Httpclient in Http/1.0 on these devices and server only allow Http1.1, so the request is rejected.

I also tried to follow the [UWP Httpclient sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/main/Samples/HttpClient/cs/Scenario01_GetText.xaml.cs) and specify the HttpBaseProtocolFilter's MaxVersion property, the issue persist.

BTW, most of devices running well with the same code.
So may I know is there any way in UWP to force the Windows.Web.Http.Httpclient to send request with HTTP/1.1.

I think this issue may relate to some system settings, but so far I have no idea how to configure it in Windows 10.

Many thanks.

Comment: The Windows.Web.Http.Httpclient will use HTTP 2.0 by default. To create HttpClient that uses HTTP 1.1 instead, you need to set the HttpBaseProtocolFilter's MaxVersion property. Are you setting the `HttpBaseProtocolFilter` before you send your first request or did you create a new HTTPClient object for the new request? Based on the comment of the sample -**if the user has already used the filter object to send at least one request, the HTTP version of the filter cannot be changed. we need to create new client and filter objects**.

Comment: But actually, it did use Http1.0 to send the request, I also tried to run the httpclient sample APP on the issued devices without changing any code, the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: I made a simple test with **HttpClient** by using `GetStringAsync` method to access https://www.bing.com on my windows 10 device and captured the http request via fiddler, it's http 1.1 not http 1.0.  It seems to be more related t with the local device. Does other app like a WPF using System.Net.Http.HttpClient have the same behavior? Or can you try to use  System.Net.Http.HttpClient in UWP app for simple test?

Comment: Thx, I will update you. Currently, I can confirm these device can access the same request with edge browser. It seems only the UWP APP can't.

Comment: Any updates about this? Does other kind of apps like WPF using System.Net.Http.HttpClient have the same issue?

Comment: I still have no change to try this on the issued device.

Comment: Both Windows.Web.Http.Httpclient and System.Net.Http.HttpClient have the same issue with UWP app. I also tried the WebView got the same issue, but WebView2 works fine. Have no change to run other exe the issued device.

Comment: Some good news, I can confirm it related to user profile. If we renew the user profile, UWP app works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, we find out the root cause of this issue.

After check the permission of HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings and compare with normal one. We found that the permission of “All Application Packages” is missing. All UWP applications work normal after adding read permission for “All Application Packages”.